How to export a very large neo4j database?
I have a Neo4j database that's approximately 40 GB in size, which I created using the Neo4j Desktop application on Windows. I want to export this database in a way that allows me to access it from Neo4j Desktop on another computer. Additionally, I need to package the database so that it can be shared via a torrent. Could someone provide detailed step-by-step instructions for exporting the database, ensuring it can be imported and accessed on the new machine, and preparing it for torrenting? Any advice on managing the transfer of such a large file would be greatly appreciated.

How to Export a Database:

Choose your DBMS (Database Management System).
Click the three dots next to the name of your selected DBMS.
Select the "Dump" option.
Wait for the export (dumping) process to complete. You will see the message Successfully dumped 'neo4j' from Graph DBMS once the export process is complete.
Transfer the dump file to your desired computer.

How to Import a Database:

Install Neo4j Desktop.
Create a new project within Neo4j Desktop.
In the project window, go to Add > File, and select the neo4j.dump file from its directory.
Wait for the dump file to show up in the bottom half of the project window and for the message neo4j.dump was added to 'Project'.
Click on the neo4j.dump file, press the three dots next to it, and select Create new DBMS from dump. Keep the default settings and set the password to "password."
Wait for the database import to finish.
Once complete, you can start the database and begin interacting with it.

